Error with a basic example using React Navigation : Element type is invalid: expected a string
I’m trying to create a local project with the latest version of React Navigation (7RC), but even for a very simple example, I keep getting this error:

Warning: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

// In App.js in a new project

import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function RootStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

When I run the same very simple example (from the documentation) on Snack, the error is the same : https://snack.expo.dev/6V2VhVWWhgJq3N3t767te (Select the Android version).
I am aware that this is an RC version (and I have tested several previous ones), but I’m surprised that it crashes right from the first lines of code.
Do you have any idea why? Thanks.

I tried using their example in a bare react-native project and it works out of the box, what I assume is the error is because of the expo v51.0.0, and the expected version might be expo >= 50

I've just found the reason: even on a React Native application without an expo, React Navigation RC is currently only compatible with React Native Screens beta :)
